# Linked Lists with vectors

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

I am trying to perform certain operations through linked lists on vectors.

We have been given a struct type vector

```
typedef struct{
int *array;   // a pointer to vector's storage
int size;     // the current number of elements in the vector
int cap;      // the current capacity of the vector;
int init_cap; // the initial capacity the vector was initialised with.
} vector;
```

Now, I want to make a function that takes in a pointer to the vector struct, and initialises it with the given capacity. All the fields are to be initialised. I want to do this using linked list.

**Here is my code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
int *array;     // a pointer to the vector's storage
int size;       // the current number of elements in the vector
int cap;        // the current capacity of the vector
int init_cap;   // the initial capacity the vector was initialised with
node *next;

} vector;

node *head = NULL;
```

Can I make nodes from a vector struct, like I have attempted in the code written above?

```
void vector_init(vector *v, int capacity){

//initialising the vector with the given capacity
v->size     = capacity;
v->cap      = capacity;
v->init_cap = capacity;

//linked list with nodes created and values initialised

node *temp, temp2;
temp = head;
temp = new node;
temp->size     = capacity;
temp->cap      = capacity;
temp->init_cap = capacity;


temp->next = temp2
temp2 = new node;
temp2->size     = capacity;
temp2->cap      = capacity;
temp2->init_cap = capacity;
    temp2->next = NULL;
}
```

Have I made the linked list, and initialised the values correctly? If we do not create temporary points temp and temp2, and just use v->size etc to initialise the fields, would that make it a linked list?

Comment: `typedef struct`, seriously? Who's teaching you that stuff?

Comment: That's a question more appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as long you don't experience any particular problems with your code.

Comment: I'd recommend not using the name `vector` for your own data structures, as this will likely conflict with the `std::vector` class, especially since you're declaring `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Okay, so if we remove using namespace std; and then use vectors as data structures, would that be okay? @djikay

Comment: It was a general point, not related to the problem at hand. It's just for readability purposes. For example, in the future another developer may come across your code and wrongly assume your vector is a std::vector.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make any sense to me. What do you want to achieve? The vector already has an array storage. There is no need to define a linked list to initialize that.

Comment: If we're staying with semantics from C++ vectors, which I'd highly recommend not to change in your example: Initializing with a capacity should keep the size at 0.

Comment: My instructor suggested to us that we can solve all types of problems using functions that involve linked lists instead of arrays. So I wanted to test this out. @dornhege

Comment: I still don't get it. Your struct has an array. What does the data structure look like that you want to build?

Comment: Well, we are supposed to implement some functions, which includes the one I have mentioned in this question (i.e. initialising values). While it is true that the struct does have a pointer to an array, but the challenge we have been given is to use linked lists to solve the problems rather than using arrays. For example, the next function requires to release any memory associated with the struct, and we also have to attempt this using linked lists. @dornhege

Comment: What is mind boggling is why a supposed "C++ instructor" would call a user-defined type a `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You have many problems with your code.

- Don't use the name **vector** - there is a structure called std::vector and it is easy to get confused.
- If you want to initialize the values of the structure, don't create an external, separate function for that - it's not c++'ish. Create a struct constructor initializing all the values instead.
- You don't initialize the **array** variable anywhere in your code. You should allocate space for it depending on the capacity given in the constructor.
- Don't use the name 'array' for the variable. There is a structure called std::array in C++, and it might be confusing.
- Your implementaion makes very little sense to me. You have a **linked list of arrays** right now; if you would like to functionally replace an **array of ints** with a **linked list of ints**, each node should contain one int value.
- If, for some reason, you would want to stick to this implementation, you also need some kind of update function that would automatically update **size** and **cap** variables while adding or removing elements from **array**. Otherwise you are sure to end up forgetting about it and you're gonna have mess in your structure. Make this function a part of the structure - it shouldn't be an external function.
- That **typedef struct node** doesn't make sense even after changing the word **vector** to something else - you don't use it anyway in your code.
- You are using the same name for two different structures; **vector** is at first defined as having 4 fields, and in the next lines as having 5 fields.

Technically yes, this is a linked list, but your **vector_init()** function does not work as it should. Apart from what I've written above:

- You should avoid making functions depend on the global variable, in this case **head**. It could be passed as a parameter.
- These two lines:

> temp = head;

```
temp = new node;
```

don't make sense. The first one makes the variable **temp** point to **head**; the second one tells temp to start pointing to the new variable as you're using operator **new**, which allocates space and return a pointer to the newly created variable. As a result, you don't operate on the variable head, when you do further operations, but on another variable that will be lost after the **temp** pointer gets invalidated.

- You don't need **temp** and **temp2** variables at all. They only bloat the code.
- These two lines:

> temp->next = temp2;

```
temp2 = new node;
```

should switch places since now you assign a pointer that hasn't been yet initialised.

- After writing all this stuff I've realised that the function is incorrect in general. For some reason, you first work on the parameter **v**, and then do something unrelated to it.

Also, your instructor is just not right saying that you can solve all types of problems with the use of linked lists. It may solve some problems in certain situations, or create new problems, depending on the context.

I don't want to be rude, but there seems to be something fundamentally wrong with the concept of the task you have been given itself. I guess someone really hasn't thought it through.

Comment: `new node;` will call default constructor, or pop error when compiling the code if one is not provided, but it is valid C++